# .NET access an infected Excel File (with a ransomware) via Microsoft Jet engine, can this affect or infect the server?

Tags: asp.net, excel, database, vb.net, security

We have a simple ASP.NET web Application that reads Excel files via an upload page and inserts rows in a database.
Users are uploading an Excel file that fills up a table in a MSSQL Database.

We are reading the Excel file via a simple code block like this.

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & filePath & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
'Get data from Exel into a DataFile
Try
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", con)
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "DataSet")
    Return ds.Tables(0)
Catch ex As Exception
    HttpContext.Current.Session("Error") = "err: " & ex.Message
    Throw ex
    Return New DataTable()
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

Can the reading of an malitios Excel file through our app infect the server running the page?

Is Jet Engine so powerful that **it may run malicious** code embedded in an infected Excel file when **accessing rows through the code**?

Comment: What is your *real* question? The Jet provider doesn't execute macros. You don't even need it to read `xlsx` files, the format used in the last 12 years. `xlsx` is a zip package of xml files. You could use the Open XML SDK or a library like Epplus to read it without installing the Jet driver

Comment: You should worry about how you insert data into the database instead. If you create dynamic SQL queries all it would take for a SQL Injection attack would be to write `'); drop table users;--` in a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, it's possible.
There is two types of malicious standard office documents in the world :

- Macro based malicious activity

Macro based infected files are not so dangerous in your case because they are some extra objects embed in document and triggered by user interaction or some codes in your application which execute the macro automatically, so if you don't have any code to execute macros inside office documents, don't worry about office douments which infected by Macro scripts!

- Exploit malicious activity

On other hand there is infected documents which contains exploits that target some bugs or logical features and etc. this files is so dangerous because they exploit the standard feature of documents (like parser). So if your underlying API or engine that parse this type of files implement and use this feature that was exploited, your program can be affected!

Finally if you want to protect the server from infection by this scenario, you should implement or use existing sandbox products which prevent the executed file from change anything on system and prevent the network and IO activity of executed file and for more security it's better to do the parse process in separate machine or VM not directly on main server and just return the result to server. but in general the sandbox solution is enough.

For example here is list of some Jet driver exploits that found just by Googling "Microsoft Jet driver Exploit":

- [MS08-028](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/950749/ms08-028-vulnerability-in-the-microsoft-jet-database-engine-could-allo)
- [CVE-2000-0325](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/19435/)
- [CVE-2005-0944](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/927/)
- [CVE-2005-0944](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/929/)

Maybe it does not happen at all because of code reviews, fuzzing, penetration testing and bug bounty behind popular softwares and tools by the security experts before releases and that's the reason why you see so much less exploits for underlying popular software and tools like Jet driver, but even in security nothing is absolute and no one can claim that his product is safe.

At the end it depends on the platform you developing and how security important  to you and your product. my answer is academic and may not occur. but even it's absolutely possible. so you should choose the best solution depending on your need and risk ;)

Comment: @Enovator the answer is at least 50% wrong. The Jet provider doesn't execute macros. Only Excel executes macros. As for `Exploit malicious activity` that would mean exploiting bugs in the *Jet provider*, not Excel. An attacker would try to exploit .NET vulnerabilities as well. The answer is to patch your system and use up-to-date drivers. No sandbox or VM will protect you - hosted and cloud servers *already* run on VMs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I say macro is not dangerous in this scenario!
and again i say if the underlying API or provider use standard implementation can be affected! so the answer is completely true. and for your answer to update the system and drivers, if today an exploit launched and the patch not even released what you do? just watch the infection ?! so don't install AV and other protection tools and just update your machine and drivers and keep relax... 
With regards; it seems you don't have good knowledge on security.
If the parse operation process in Sandbox, it's more secure.

Comment: The OP is using the ACE driver. I didn't find any exploits listed with "Microsoft ace driver Exploit". Of course, that doesn't mean that there aren't any, but could it be that the ACE driver uses some sort of sandbox technology itself?

Comment: @Enovator Latest Jet engine exploit : https://www.thezdi.com/blog/2018/9/20/zdi-can-6135-a-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-in-the-microsoft-windows-jet-database-engine